# Saving multiple names and emails in a single table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I save multiple names and emails inside the database? For example i have a table called "Gname". Inside the table i have columns for 'Name' and 'Email'.

I want to be able to store multiple name and emails in one of my forms. If i need 9 names and email it should be able to store. I have listed the code below

```
<%= f.fields_for :gname, Gname.new do |u| %>
  <p class="title">Group Names & Emails</p>
  <div class="group">
    <%= u.text_field :name, placeholder:'Physician Name', class: "half" %>
    <%= u.text_field :email, placeholder:'Physician email', class: "half" %>
    <div class="push"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <%= u.text_field :name, placeholder:'Physician Name', class: "half" %>
    <%= u.text_field :email, placeholder:'Physician email', class: "half" %>
    <div class="push"></div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You need to create gname instances in the controller  through it's parent model. eg `9.times { @parent.gnames.build }` and use `f.fields_for :gnames`. Or just use the great `cocoon` gem

Answer (score 0):

You can use Cocoon gem to achieve this.
**https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon**

This will help you generate as many forms you want on the web page for a particular model.
This will also help you edit them simultaneously.
Also, this can be used for child models as well.